# Angular 2 : MockBackend returning 'undefined' response

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am trying to write up a unit test for my service using MockBackend and each time  I get a response as undefined. Any help would be appreciated.
I have checked all these solutions below and compared to mine I really don't see much differences.

- [Test Angular2 service with mock backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829751/test-angular2-service-with-mock-backend)
- [How to use MockBackend in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526079/how-to-use-mockbackend-in-angular2)

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { SomeObject } from './someObject';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    private serviceUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/getObjects';  

    constructor( private http: Http ) { }

    getObjects() {
        return this.http.get( this.serviceUrl )
            .map(( response ) => response.json().content as SomeObject[])
    }
}
```

Here is my tests:

```
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { TestBed, tick, fakeAsync, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';
import { SomeObject } from './someObject';

describe( 'SomeServiceTest', () => {

    let stubData: SomeObject[] = [
        new SomeObject( 1, "Title" )
    ];

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            providers: [
                SomeService,
                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: ( backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions ) => {
                        return new Http( backend, options );
                    },
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
                }
            ]
        });
    });

    it( 'should fetch data', inject( [SomeService, MockBackend], fakeAsync(( service: SomeService, mockBackend: MockBackend ) => {
        let res: SomeObject[];
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe( c => {
            expect( c.request.url ).toBe( 'http://localhost:8080/getObjects' );
            c.mockRespond( new Response( new ResponseOptions( {
                body: JSON.stringify( stubData )
            }) ) );
        });

        service.getObjects().subscribe(( response ) => {
            console.log( "response :: " + JSON.stringify( response ) ); // this is where I am seeing undefined
            res = response;
        });

        tick();

        expect( res[0].name ).toBe( 'Title' ); // this returns an exception TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    }) ) );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I believe your issue is, first, that you are returning `response.json().content as Object[]` from your  from your service.the `content` property is most likely undefined. I would suggest just mapping your response to a json object and having your component handle it.

```
getObjects() {
    return this.http.get( this.dealsUrl )
        .map(( response ) => response.json());
}
```

Then

```
service.getSomeObjectsUsingObservable().subscribe(( response ) => {
    console.log( "response :: " + JSON.stringify( response ) );
    if (response.content){
        res = response as SomeObject[];
    }
    else {
        //- fail test
    }
});
tick();
expect( res[0].name ).toBe( 'Title' );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Fixing the response from `response.json().content as SomeObject[]` to `response.json()` solved it.

The second correction you suggested is not really the problem as you can see I have used `fakeAsync` in conjunction with `tick()` which handles my asynchronous calls.

However, I still will accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll update my answer for future reference! Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel !! A second set of eyes always helps. I knew there was nothing wrong with the configuration and there is always a silly mistake behind these ;)