# Angular 4 test with MockBackend returns Promise

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I copied and use the same code as you can see in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753593/angular-2-mockbackend-returning-undefined-response) including the answer. My Angular dependency versions in `package.json` are set to 4.0.2, NodeJS has 7.5.0 and NPM has 4.1.2.

When I start the test `response` seems to be a `Promise` in my case.

`expect(res).toBe(0);` leads to the message `Expected [object Promise] to be 0.` on console. `expect(res.length).toBe(0);` ends with `Expected undefined to be 0.`

When I use the second example from official [doc](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html) the same thing happens.

The same issue can recreated with Angular 4.0.0 dependencies.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are u resolving the promise from the response? Could u show us?

Comment: I used the method `then`. Right now I can't remember the behavior of it. Normally I should expect the stub data there?

Comment: I run the code and added a `then` call to `response` parameter. This causes the error message `Property 'then' is missing in type 'SomeObject[]'.`

Comment: I've just got the same. In the code response.json() works fine at runtime, but when testing it says response.json() returns a promise and fails.
`this.lastConnection.mockRespond(
        new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: JSON.stringify(myData)}))
);`

Which I took right from the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html). I haven't solved it yet. Must be something simple. In the mean time I just stubbed json().
`this.lastConnection.mockRespond({
        body: myData,
        json: () => myData
 });`

This works fine for now.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I've spent way too much time fighting with it.

Comment: Caused by this issue I write plain unit test without Angular context (TestBed).

Comment: same problem here. Justin's workaround is working just fine, but it would be awesome to understand what is causing that

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are importing the correct Response object.

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: actually this seems to be pretty unfortunate and confusing as `lib.es6` `Response` does not need `import` and the only indicator is other signature.

Comment: You rock! My head was spinning. Thanks a million.
And I agree with @blacksheep_2011. It's not odd that we're getting the wrong Response, but it's a pretty odd reaction from mockRespond. It should really throw an error as it's so easy to make the mistake, and the current behavior does nothing to help.

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a ton. This saved me. Spent so much time on this one.